# Div get full height of remaining area

Tags: html, css

I have a problem. I have a page with 3 divs: image, title and content like this

```
<style>
.container {
    padding: 20px;
    display: table;
    background: darkgrey;
}
.title-wrap, .content-wrap {
    width: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.img-wrap {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
}

.img-wrap img {
    width: 100%;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .img-wrap {
        width: 40%;
    }

    .title-wrap, .content-wrap{
        width: 51%;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1220px) {
    .content-wrap {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

```
<div class="container">
<div class="img-wrap">
    <img src="http://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/5.jpg" />
</div>

<div class="title-wrap">
    <h1>Title here</h1>
    <h3>Subtitle here</h3>
    <p>Aenean egestas quam nisi, nec eleifend lectus vehicula aliquet</p>
</div>

<div class="content-wrap">
    <p>Sed auctor, nibh at semper fringilla, justo ante sollicitudin ligula, sed rutrum dui nisl ac diam. Nulla feugiat diam porta quam blandit ultricies. Curabitur rutrum eget nunc non mollis. Morbi orci lectus, fermentum vel purus id, elementum volutpat diam. Duis mauris eros, dapibus sit amet cursus lobortis, ultrices nec metus. Proin at est tempor velit malesuada scelerisque ut aliquet velit. Fusce at luctus sem. Suspendisse condimentum blandit est, sit amet vestibulum nisi commodo eu. Duis laoreet dolor lacus, vitae pellentesque augue varius vel. Mauris facilisis, libero id consectetur luctus, massa eros sodales eros, in sodales felis felis quis urna. Quisque sodales nibh ipsum, eget tristique diam bibendum nec. Maecenas maximus magna efficitur nulla faucibus vulputate. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Praesent sit amet sapien non nibh rhoncus bibendum. Mauris varius felis elit, ut luctus neque feugiat non.</p>
    <p>Sed posuere dolor erat, in lacinia felis sodales sit amet. Sed pulvinar finibus nisl, a pellentesque odio tincidunt id. Nulla blandit pellentesque nisi, vel fringilla tellus. In posuere laoreet urna, vel convallis nunc tempor non. Proin libero purus, semper eget tincidunt luctus, dapibus vitae risus. Nullam mattis feugiat sapien, vitae facilisis leo dapibus non. Mauris lobortis sem lectus, sed auctor quam egestas euismod. Sed ornare enim maximus, dictum tortor vitae, lobortis nisi. Cras et urna dignissim, vehicula purus eu, rhoncus sem. Ut tristique accumsan ante, id eleifend ipsum.</p>
</div>
```

I want the image display in center vertical of the right column of page in desktop version (devices with the width from 768px to 1220px) but currently it is in the top of image div. I guest this problem occurs because of the height of image div. I have google all day but seems no solution works. Could you help me to do this work?

Thank in advance.

P/s: I have created jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/6px1yefv/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that with the display type "flex" and the height of "100vh" (stands for 100% viewport height)

Add the following attributes to your CSS classes:

```
.container {
    height: 100vh;
}

.img-wrap {
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
```

As a side note: avoid using table display type for divs such as for .container in your code, this practice is very outdated in terms of modern UI development practices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works, but when user use their phone to access this page, it only show the image first (because this image is 100% viewport height), and they don't see any contain. The same problem for desktop version (min-width: 1220px)

Comment: Try also deleting your last media query. I.e. `@media screen and (min-width: 1220px) {..content-wrap { width: 100%;} }`, See revised [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6px1yefv/6/)

Comment: Ooops! I provided incorrect link to fiddle in my previous comment. Here is the correct [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6px1yefv/7/).

Comment: Thanks @RobC and Bakr Kawkji, you saved my day :)